# Jetpack Compose animation performance issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm new to Jetpack Compose, and I'm trying to rotate the home screen with animation when the menu button is tapped. It works fine 3-5 times, but suddenly it lags like crazy and I don't know why? Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

```kotlin
var isOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val transition = updateTransition(targetState = isOpen, "Menu")

val rotation by transition.animateFloat(
    transitionSpec = { spring(0.4f, Spring.StiffnessLow) },
    label = "MenuRotation",
    targetValueByState = { if (it) -30f else 0f }
)

val scale by transition.animateFloat(
    label = "MenuScale",
    targetValueByState = { if (it) 0.9f else 1f }
)

val translateX by transition.animateFloat(
    transitionSpec = { tween(400) },
    label = "MenuTranslation",
    targetValueByState = { if (it) 536f else 0f }
)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .graphicsLayer {
            cameraDistance = density * 10f
            rotationY = rotation
            scaleX = scale
            translationX = translateX
        }
) {
    HomeScreen()
}

Box {
   DefaultButton(
        onClick = { isOpen = ! isOpen },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .padding(top = 32.dp)
            .shadow(blur = 8.dp, radius = 16.dp)
            .size(32.dp, 32.dp),
        shape = Shapes.large,
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = if (isOpen) Icons.Filled.Close else Icons.Filled.Menu,
            contentDescription = "Menu",
            tint = Color.Black,
        )
    }
}
```

**Update #1**

I found this in the logcat

Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Davey! duration=1067ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=2511155, IntendedVsync=4294436921331, Vsync=4294870254647, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=4294871069349, AnimationStart=4294871070287, PerformTraversalsStart=4294871939089, DrawStart=4294872039558, FrameDeadline=4294486921330, FrameInterval=4294870971954, FrameStartTime=41666666, SyncQueued=4294872645860, SyncStart=4295312217578, IssueDrawCommandsStart=4295312304089, SwapBuffers=4295937520703, FrameCompleted=4295944298047, DequeueBufferDuration=5729, QueueBufferDuration=166719, GpuCompleted=4295944298047, SwapBuffersCompleted=4295937862943, DisplayPresentTime=4237530536663, CommandSubmissionCompleted=4295937520703,

**Update #2**

The animation works flawlessly when I comment out all text components and vice versa. So what's wrong with the text components?

Comment: Have you tried testing it in Release mode instead? Debug mode can be slow.

Comment: Yes, the same thing happened in release mode too

Comment: Have you checked logcat? Perhaps there is more info there

Answer (score 2):

Please check the HomeScreen composable, component recomposition counts。

I suspect that HomeScreen reorganizes too many times。

You can just replace `@Composable HomeScreen` with an `@Composeable Image` verify。

Comment: The animation works flawlessly when I comment out all text components and vice versa. So what's wrong with the text components?

Comment: Yes there are no lags, If I replace the HomeScreen with Image. Also, the recomposition counts in the layout inspector shows nothing (empty).

Comment: It should be that there are too many reorganizations of composable subitems in your `@Composable HomeScreen`, you can use the LayoutInspector tool of AndroidStudio to debug component recomposition counts

Answer (score 0):

Drawing text is a surprisingly expensive operation, and not only in Compose. Text is generally drawn (serially) with the CPU, while an image is manipulated (in parallel) by the GPU.

Look at the [Draw text](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview#draw-text) section of the Compose Graphics Overview guide. It suggests using Modifier.drawWithCache to alleviate the expensiveness problem when drawing text in a DrawScope. I do not know if this will help when animating as you do.

Also, it does not explain why your animation works fine a few times, and then lags.

In a different context, I have drawn text once on a bitmap at the screen resolution, then animated the bitmap as an image for speed. You may want to try drawing your HomeScreen to a bitmap first.