# Jetpack Compose Performance Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a simple word game, building the ui with compose. [link to Repo](https://github.com/tylerwilbanks/word-game-android)

The issue: After about 5 seconds or so of interacting with the ui, the app will begin an extreme slowdown, frozen.

Here is the logcat output:

```
2023-08-16 08:05:50.236  3083-3083  ViewRootIm...nActivity] com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Creating frameCommitCallback commitCallbacks size=1
2023-08-16 08:05:50.257  3083-3103  OpenGLRenderer          com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Davey! duration=11259ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=733165084, IntendedVsync=2022710695472824, Vsync=2022716243881704, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=2022716254391621, AnimationStart=2022716254394121, PerformTraversalsStart=2022716254847194, DrawStart=2022716255107559, FrameDeadline=2022710778856848, FrameInterval=2022716254275996, FrameStartTime=41717360, SyncQueued=2022716255742663, SyncStart=2022721921235994, IssueDrawCommandsStart=2022721921442244, SwapBuffers=2022727614530211, FrameCompleted=2022727620406513, DequeueBufferDuration=13698, QueueBufferDuration=282448, GpuCompleted=2022727620406513, SwapBuffersCompleted=2022727615074846, DisplayPresentTime=2022632778940038, CommandSubmissionCompleted=2022727614530211, 
2023-08-16 08:05:56.007  3083-3083  Choreographer           com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Skipped 137 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-08-16 08:05:56.014  3083-3917  OpenGLRenderer          com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Davey! duration=11445ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=733166030, IntendedVsync=2022716286622303, Vsync=2022721918474273, InputEventId=267435281, HandleInputStart=2022721937898338, AnimationStart=2022721937900473, PerformTraversalsStart=2022721950299692, DrawStart=2022721950456776, FrameDeadline=2022716370006389, FrameInterval=2022721937800421, FrameStartTime=41717422, SyncQueued=2022721955300005, SyncStart=2022727621745159, IssueDrawCommandsStart=2022727622009117, SwapBuffers=2022733393287605, FrameCompleted=2022733399056823, DequeueBufferDuration=16041, QueueBufferDuration=304948, GpuCompleted=2022733399056823, SwapBuffersCompleted=2022733393854167, DisplayPresentTime=2022632787273372, CommandSubmissionCompleted=2022733393287605, 
2023-08-16 08:06:01.772  3083-3133  ViewRootIm...nActivity] com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Received frameCommitCallback didProduceBuffer=true
2023-08-16 08:06:01.782  3083-3083  Choreographer           com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-08-16 08:06:01.783  3083-3083  ViewRootIm...nActivity] com.minutesock.wordgame              I  Creating frameCommitCallback commitCallbacks size=1
```

My ui is not unnecessarily recomposing. The text animates which is why the count is higher than the rest, but I see that re-composition is being skipped as it should. You can also see the top word row as the highest recomp count because it was the only row I was editing. That is good news there.

[image: Recomposition counts]

I know all of my composable parameters are stable because of this output from the compose compiler:

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun DailyWordScreen(
  stable state: DailyWordState
  stable guessWords: SnapshotStateList<GuessWord>
  stable onEvent: Function1<DailyWordEvent, Unit>
  stable falseKeyboardKeys: FalseKeyboardKeys
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun FalseKeyboard(
  stable falseKeyboardKeys: FalseKeyboardKeys
  stable onEvent: Function1<DailyWordEvent, Unit>
  stable guessKeys: ImmutableList<GuessKey>
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun FalseKeyboardLetter(
  stable onEvent: Function1<DailyWordEvent, Unit>
  stable displayText: String
  stable guessKeys: ImmutableList<GuessKey>
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun LetterBox(
  stable letter: GuessLetter
  stable guessWordState: GuessWordState
  stable onEvent: Function1<DailyWordEvent, Unit>
  stable flipAnimDelay: Int
  stable isFinalLetterInRow: Boolean
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun WordRow(
  stable guessWord: GuessWord
  stable guessLetters: ImmutableList<GuessLetter>
  stable onEvent: Function1<DailyWordEvent, Unit>
)
restartable skippable scheme("[0, [0]]") fun WordGameTheme(
  stable useDarkTheme: Boolean = @dynamic isSystemInDarkTheme($composer, 0)
  stable content: Function2<Composer, Int, Unit>
)
fun rememberShakeController()
fun asString(
  stable <this>: UiText
): String
```

Finally, I am still lead to believe this is a compose problem because the frame skips only begin after interacting with the ui a few times, and my business logic is simple + being executed in coroutines. The render thread goes crazy once the frame skips start.

[image: Profiler output]

EDIT: I have built the app in release mode with R8, I still get the same result.

In my project build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: I believe I have found the offending ui code causing the slowdown, but I do not understand why it is a problem.

```
@Composable
fun FalseKeyboardLetter(
    onEvent: (DailyWordEvent) -> Unit,
    guessKey: GuessKey,
) {
var flipRotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

LaunchedEffect(guessKey.state) {
        animate(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = 360f,
            animationSpec = tween(1000)
        ) { value: Float, _: Float ->
            flipRotation = value
        }
    }
}
```

Upon commenting out `flipRotation = value` in my `launchedEffect`, everything plays out normally, no more ui freeze, no more `Davey! skipped 150 frames!` in the logcat. It is my understanding that `launchedEffect` only gets called when the `key` changes. `guessKey.state` is a value that only gets updated when I press enter, so very infrequent, yet the app performance tanks even when `guessKey.state` never changes (in testing, never pressing enter to update `guessKey.state`). What gives?

Comment: Could the problem be expensive text drawing? See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040826/jetpack-compose-animation-performance-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Try in release build with R8 compiler. Debug mode is good for finding problems, but it costs the performance significantly.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#build-release

Comment: I have built with the R8 compiler. Still the same result.